# How do I read the contents of stack variables in IDA?

Tags: reverse-engineering, ida

I notice that a char buffer has been allocated on the stack in a function. It goes like this:

```
.text:00401xxx Buffer= byte ptr -24h
```

I know that I can read Dwords at memory addresses by going:

```
Dword(0x<address>)
```

But, how do I do the same for stack variables? Specifically here, I'd like to be able to read the whole character buffer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuo could use the [idc](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc-module.html) IDA module, there are many interesting functions.

If you want print dword, this is correct:
 `Dword(0x<address>)`

For memory dumping as suggest above you could use follow function:

```
**GetManyBytes(ea, size, use_dbg=False)<br>**
Parameters:
        ea - linear address
        size - size of buffer in normal 8-bit bytes
        use_dbg - if True, use debugger memory, otherwise just the database
```

An example:

```
GetManyBytes(0x<address>, 50, True)
```

You can call the function runtime, you could use also a simple script like:

```
from idc import GetManyBytes
from struct import unpack

def simple_dump():
    arr = []
    for i in xrange(0, 2*SIZE_TO_DUMP, 2):
        bytes = GetManyBytes(0x<address>+i,2)
        arr.append(unpack("h", bytes)[0])
    return arr

def main():
    values = simple_dump()
```

You can also use the IDA Hex-View windows